# How to transfer data from PHP to Smarty?

Tags: javascript, php, smarty

I have a project that uses Smarty files, but i don't understand how are they parsed from PHP to tpl. I understand that from tpl files to PHP are parsed with js that uses AJAX.
And please share some good AJAX guides, i mostly find people using this nonsense to parse PHP data to javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          var a = <?php echo json_encode($var); ?>;
         </script>
```

Comment: Thats what GOOGLE was built for. And the manuals are also there for a purpose

Comment: I have read the smarty documentation and there is nothing that is in the project

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yahoo! was there before GooOOoooogle was; maybe that's busted too.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I always liked to `Ask Geeves`, seemed like such a polite way to search the internet

Comment: @RiggsFolly *Aye,* true enough Squire.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions in the project there is no $smarty object and no $smarty->assign(...)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Seemed almost like sitting down to Tea and Crumpets with the Butler, _Dont ya know_

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions thats why i'm here to get answers, cause google only has basic $smarty->assign answer

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions well if you can't be professional and gonna be emotional then i don't get it why are you even her. I asked a question and waiting and answer for it, i didn't said i have a problem in code. I asked if there is other ways to parse data from php to tpl, if you don't get it then please don't spam useless stuff, thank you

Comment: First you come up with _nonsense_ argument.... But if you come to some places, better read the rules http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, thing you are in the wrong place, have a nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To parse data to smarty template I needed to parse the variable in `data` array or in some modules  parse `object_data['data']` array